# How can I assign every 4 lines to a variable when using StreamReader?

Tags: c#

I've created a for loop to read lines from a .txt file and want to assign the first line to one variable (first name), the second line to another, their last name, the third line to their corresponding pay, and the fourth line to their employee type. While this works great for the information of one person, I'm having trouble making it work for multiple employees. When I use i to assign the firstname variable to every 4th line, I'm given this error:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
frmEmployee form = new frmEmployee();
EmployeeInfo employeeInfo = new EmployeeInfo(fname, lname, empPay, empType);

fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
string line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sr.ReadLine().Length; i++){
        //Works for one employee, but not multiple
        fname = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ElementAt(0);
        lname = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ElementAt(1);
        empPay = Double.Parse(File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ElementAt(2));
        empType = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ElementAt(3);

        //Attempt to assign variables to multiple employees

        //fname = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ElementAt(0 + (4*i));
        //lname = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ElementAt(1 + (4*i));
        //empPay = Double.Parse(File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ElementAt(2 + (4*i));
        //empType = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ElementAt(3 + (4*i));
    }
```

Comment: You'll want to look into the many fine CSV Parsing tools available as you have multiple serious issues in your code.  Reading CSV files is more problematic than you would think

Comment: Don't call 'File.ReadAllLines()' so often for the same file. also you don't need a streamreader if you decide to use file.readalllines() and vice versa, just decide to do one method of reading the file

Comment: You are reading the whole file for every line you use. You are also using the length of a random line as your iterator `i`, so if `4*i` is greater than the length of the file you will get the ArgumentOutOfRange exception. You only create a single EmployeeInfo object. Try reading the file (ReadAllLines) into an array and iterate over the array, then come back, edit your post and we will be able to give more constructive help.

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp - the poster did not say it is CSV

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < sr.ReadLine().Length; i++)` - first, this will read a line without assigning it to anything. But it also means that you're using the length of a single line to determine how many times to execute the loop. If it's `Bob` that's three times. If that's `Ailce` then five times.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use a `for` loop where you start the counter at `3` (since arrays are zero-based, this is the fourth index), and increments by `4` on each iteration. This way you're reading `4` lines, then skipping to the next set. Then you can just create a new employee from the `4` lines and add it to a list.

For example:

```
private static List<EmployeeInfo> GetEmployees(string filePath)
{
    var employees = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
    var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    for (var i = 3; i < fileLines.Length; i += 4)
    {
        employees.Add(new EmployeeInfo(fileLines[i - 3], fileLines[i - 2], 
            fileLines[i - 1], fileLines[i]));
    }

    return employees;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, there are two conflicting methods being used to  reading the contents of the file.  **StreamReader.ReadLine()** will read the next line, and progress and internal pointer in that reader.   **File.ReadAllLines()** reads all the lines at once into a string array in memory, easily accessible to your code.

Assuming your file is not huge, I think it's probably simplest to use the File.ReadAllLines to load all the file contents into an array, and then step through that building your collection of Employee objects.

Something like this might help:

```
var contents = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);     // Load all lines into local array
var employeeCount = contents.Length / 4;        // Figure out how many employees are there
var employees = new EmployeeInfo[employeeCount];

for (int i = 0; i < employeeCount; i++)
{
    var offset = (i * 4);                       // Set a base offset based on the current empl.
    employees[i] = new EmployeeInfo
    {
        fname = contents.ElementAt(offset),
        lname = contents.ElementAt(offset + 1),
        empPay = Double.Parse(contents.ElementAt(offset + 2)),
        empType = contents.ElementAt(offset + 3),
    };
}
```